# client.wait_for() but for multiple things

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, discord.py

I have this code below that works but its in order so if you wanna ask about the kick command it wont show you unless you ask about the ban command first etc. I would like it to be so that you can ask about any of the commands no matter what order you do it in so if someone needs help with the kick command they don't need to ask about the ban command first etc:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == message.channel and m.author != client.user
    if message.content.startswith("?helptest"):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send(f"Which command would you like help with?")

        ban_message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send("Sends ban one")

        kick_message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send("Sends kick one")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ban_message` and `kick_message` simply return a message object, you can check if the user says a specific key word, for example `ban` or `kick`. Do view the example below:

```py
while True: # Runs this wait_for until a valid option is chosen
    user_message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    # user_message.content returns whatever the user said
    if user_message.content.lower() == "ban":
        await channel.send("Sends ban one")
        break
    elif user_message.content.lower() == "kick":
        await channel.send("Sends kick one")
        break
    else:
        await channel.send("Other response")
        # no break here to restart the loop
```

[image: Working as expected]

Also, as a side note, it's recommended to use the command extension because it is alot simpler and it helps ensure your code doesn't look like 'pancake code'. [You can read more about them here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html)